# JavaFX, TextField value to variable

Tags: javafx, textfield

I am trying to get the users input from a text box and set it as a variable but I dont know how. I have written and tried the following code:

```
btn = new Button("set speed");
TextField speedinput = new TextField();

btn.setOnAction(car.speed = Integer.parseInt(speedinput));
```

Any help would be great, thanks:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [official docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/text-field.htm) for TextField and [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/ButtonSample.java.html) for Button:

```
btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            car.speed = Integer.parseInt(speedinput.getText());
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, however im still getting an error.
 
'The method setOnAction(EventHandler<ActionEvent>) in the type ButtonBase is not applicable for the arguments (int)'

Any idea wha would be causing this? thanks

Comment: I edited code, but why don't you use docs as I suggested at the beginning?